# Scala, case object with productIterator-able fields?

Tags: scala

I'd like to use a case object as a typo-safe way to access members of a finite set, however this set also needs to be passed to an API as a proper `Set`.

I figured that I could do something like:

```
case object KnownFruits(
    banana     = "banana"
    apple      = "apple"
    watermelon = "watermelon")

val knownFruitsSet = KnownFruits.productIterator.toSet.asInstanceOf[Set[String]]
```

tragically, this doesn't even compile. declaring the values in the body of `KnownFruits` also doesn't work, presumably because `productIterator` only iterates over the constructor parameters of case classes/objects.

I imagine case objects can't be given parameters because there is a more desirable way of achieving this kind of use-case?

Comment: **Scala 2** or **Scala 3** and are you open to using third party libraries?

Comment: Maybe take a look at `StringEnumEntry` from [enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum)? Looks like your use case is enum-like.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez scala 3, and no libraries at the moment. the right way is probably to do with this macros so until it's extreme enough to warrant that I'm looking for quick tricks instead lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **Scala 3** then all you need to use is an `enum`, like this:

```scala
enum Fruits:
  case Banana, Apple, Watermelon
object Fruits:
  val names: Set[String] =
    values.map(_.toString).toSet
end Fruits
```

*See the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/XCdJi3p5SYast9Y97MQ8Xg)*.

Comment: I... totally forgot about using enums because the cases usually start with a capital letter and my actual use case requires these be files which are lower-cased. but this might be a case where bending those rules makes sense

Comment: @PopKernel or, you now, just add a `toLowerCase` on the `map`

Comment: also a good point, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) approach.

```
case object KnownFruits {
  val banana     = "banana"
  val apple      = "apple"
  val watermelon = "watermelon"

  def toSet: Set[String] =
    Set(banana, apple, watermelon)

}
```

A bit more typing, yes. But far less "magic" and very obvious what it's doing at a glance.

```
val knownFruitsSet = KnownFruits.toSet
```

Comment: this is what I'm going with in the meantime, the only real issue with this is that there's no way to assert the set output contains all members of KnownFruits which could lead to hard-to-solve bugs...